# Python, MYSQL How can I add together (sum of the numbers) two columns from two separate list into a new one?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, count, sum

I have two lists, result6 and result7.
result6 looks like this:

```
(2, Decimal('2'))
(17, Decimal('1'))
(16, Decimal('0'))
(15, Decimal('1'))
(9, Decimal('0'))
(5, Decimal('1'))
(4, Decimal('2'))
(13, Decimal('2'))
(18, Decimal('0'))
(7, Decimal('0'))
(12, Decimal('0'))
(11, Decimal('0'))
(10, Decimal('0'))
(3, Decimal('1'))
(1, Decimal('1'))
(14, Decimal('0'))
(8, Decimal('1'))
(6, Decimal('0'))
```

result7 looks like this:

```
(2, Decimal('0'))
(17, Decimal('1'))
(16, Decimal('1'))
(15, Decimal('1'))
(9, Decimal('2'))
(5, Decimal('0'))
(4, Decimal('0'))
(13, Decimal('0'))
(18, Decimal('0'))
(7, Decimal('1'))
(12, Decimal('0'))
(11, Decimal('1'))
(10, Decimal('0'))
(3, Decimal('0'))
(1, Decimal('0'))
(14, Decimal('1'))
(8, Decimal('0'))
(6, Decimal('0'))
```

The first column in the two lists are the references (for teams), so I want to make a new list(=result8), swap the two column (because of MYSQL update) and add together(sum of them) result6's and result7's decimal numbers in result8's first column.

```
my_sq14 = "SELECT H_code, SUM(Home_win) FROM bundesliga_2020_2021_2 GROUP BY H_code"
my_cursor.execute(my_sq14)
result6 = my_cursor.fetchall()

print("This is result6:")
for row in result6:
    print(row)

my_sq15 = "SELECT H_code, SUM(Away_win) FROM bundesliga_2020_2021_2 GROUP BY H_code"
my_cursor.execute(my_sq15)
result7 = my_cursor.fetchall()

print("This is result7:")
for row in result7:
    print(row)

result8 = []
while k < 18:
    result8.append((result6[k][1], result6[k][0]))
    k += 1

print("This is result8 first:")
for row in result8:
    print(row)


while k < 18:
    result8[k][0] = result6[k][1] + result7[k][1]
    k += 1

print("This is result8 second:")
for row in result8:
    print(row)
```

I'm not getting an error, but nothing happen, everything stays in the same, but for example at number 17 I need 2 on the other column, not 1.
Can you help me pls, where am I wrong?

result8 after swap:

```
This is result8 first:
(Decimal('2'), 2)
(Decimal('1'), 17)
(Decimal('0'), 16)
(Decimal('1'), 15)
(Decimal('0'), 9)
(Decimal('1'), 5)
(Decimal('2'), 4)
(Decimal('2'), 13)
(Decimal('0'), 18)
(Decimal('0'), 7)
(Decimal('0'), 12)
(Decimal('0'), 11)
(Decimal('0'), 10)
(Decimal('1'), 3)
(Decimal('1'), 1)
(Decimal('0'), 14)
(Decimal('1'), 8)
(Decimal('0'), 6)
```

result8 after trying to add together:

```
This is result8 second:
(Decimal('2'), 2)
(Decimal('1'), 17)
(Decimal('0'), 16)
(Decimal('1'), 15)
(Decimal('0'), 9)
(Decimal('1'), 5)
(Decimal('2'), 4)
(Decimal('2'), 13)
(Decimal('0'), 18)
(Decimal('0'), 7)
(Decimal('0'), 12)
(Decimal('0'), 11)
(Decimal('0'), 10)
(Decimal('1'), 3)
(Decimal('1'), 1)
(Decimal('0'), 14)
(Decimal('1'), 8)
(Decimal('0'), 6)
```

Comment: Side note: You didn't really disclose your schema (which you should have done) but the name `bundesliga_2020_2021_2` let's me guess the table stores the result of the matches in the Bundesliga in the season 2020/2021, probably the 2. Bundesliga. I guess there are other tables with the same schema but different seasons and classes. If that holds true, you should fix your schema. There should be only one such table and the season and the class should be denoted in columns in that table. Relational tables aren't spreadsheets, they represent relations.

Comment: My schema is this: one season in one championship (right now Bundesliga) all of the matches (but just Bundesliga 1.) in one table. Is that wrong?

Comment: If the next season would go into another table then yes, that's wrong. If it's all in one table then it's OK, only the table name is a little misleading then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to do this in Python.Why not generate the expected resultset directly in the database?

```
select h_code, sum(home_win) as home_win, sum(away_win) as away_win,
    sum(home_win) + sum(away_win) as total_wins
from bundesliga_2020_2021_2 
group by h_code
```

Comment: Thank you! Because I'm still learning this thing and still are moments, when I dont understand things, right now, there are results for example what somehow dont count in the sum, but in the table, there is a win...